# If I use clay tempering, can I take a thin piece of steel and make it hard as a very thick piece?

Tags: heat-treatment

If I use the forging process of clay tempering, can I take a thinner piece of steel and and make it as strong as a very thick piece of steel? Getting the same strength, without the extra weight?